# Call to 0x00...02 in remix debug trace

Tags: remix, contract-invocation, evm

I'm currently trying to reenact a random transaction and I've come across a weird call to `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002`. Even weirder, this call seems to actually do something since the memory at address `0x60-0x7f` is changed afterwards.

Can someone explain what is happening here?

[Here's a link](http://etherscan.io/remix?txhash=0x6e9005ccc4ff6ff0e68be19cbd8a9ed98c104d8b98aa19cae41e87b690d559e1) to the remix debug trace. It's instruction 2610.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it. Address 1, 2, 3 and 4 are builtin contracts for ecrecover, sha256, ripemd160 and identity respectively.